# Hide default monitor message when turning screen off

Tags: pi-3

I'm trying to turn the monitor off via my RPI, which works well using either

```
vcgencmd display_power 0
```

Or

```
tvservice --off
```

But then, with both of them, it shows a default message saying something like "Cable not connected". Is there any way to block it or hide it or use any other command that might not end up in the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your monitor supports HDMI [CEC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/commands-for-using-cec-client) commands. Try installing `cec-client` and running

```
echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s
```

to see if it does.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Also running `echo 'scan' | cec-client -s -d 1` doesn't show my monitor. Thanks for the suggestion though...